# Deprecated API for rawtypes warning in Java

Tags: java, deprecation-warning, raw-types

While running my code I am getting a warning for my code as shown below:

```
javac HashedDictionaryOpenAddressingLinear.java -Xlint
HashedDictionaryOpenAddressingLinear.java:54: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: HashedDictionaryOpenAddressingLinear.TableEntry
    TableEntry<K,V>[] temp = (TableEntry<K,V>[]) new TableEntry[tableSize];
                                                     ^
missing type arguments for generic class HashedDictionaryOpenAddressingLinear<K,V>.TableEntry<S,T>
where S,T,K,V are type-variables:
S extends Object declared in class HashedDictionaryOpenAddressingLinear.TableEntry
T extends Object declared in class HashedDictionaryOpenAddressingLinear.TableEntry
K extends Object declared in class HashedDictionaryOpenAddressingLinear
V extends Object declared in class HashedDictionaryOpenAddressingLinear

HashedDictionaryOpenAddressingLinear.java:243: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: HashedDictionaryOpenAddressingLinear.TableEntry
            hashTable[index] = new TableEntry(key, value);
                                   ^
missing type arguments for generic class HashedDictionaryOpenAddressingLinear<K,V>.TableEntry<S,T>
where S,T,K,V are type-variables:
S extends Object declared in class HashedDictionaryOpenAddressingLinear.TableEntry
T extends Object declared in class HashedDictionaryOpenAddressingLinear.TableEntry
K extends Object declared in class HashedDictionaryOpenAddressingLinear
V extends Object declared in class HashedDictionaryOpenAddressingLinear
```

The actual code for the warnings are shown below:-
Actual code for warning on line 54:

```
public HashedDictionaryOpenAddressingLinear(int initialCapacity)
{
    checkCapacity(initialCapacity);
    numberOfEntries = 0;

    // Set up hash table: Initial size of hash table is same as 
    // initialCapacity if it is prime otherwise increase it until it is 
    // prime size
    tableSize = getNextPrime(initialCapacity);
    checkSize(tableSize);                   // Check for max array size

    // The case is safe because the new array contains null entries
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    TableEntry<K,V>[] temp = (TableEntry<K,V>[]) new TableEntry[tableSize];    // LINE 54 CAUSING WARNING FOR RAWTYPE
    hashTable = temp;
    initialized = true;
} // end constructor
```

Actual code for warning on line 243:

```
@Override
public V add(K key, V value) 
{
    checkInitialization();

    if((key == null) || (value == null)) 
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    } 
    else 
    {
        V oldValue;                     // Value to return

        int index = getHashIndex(key);
        index = probe(index, key);      // Check for and resolve collision

        // Assertion: index is within legal range for hashTable
        assert (index >= 0) && (index < hashTable.length);

        if((hashTable[index] == null) || hashTable[index].isRemoved()) 
        {   // Key not found, so insert new entry
            hashTable[index] = new TableEntry(key, value);    // LINE 243 CAUSING WARNING FOR RAWTYPE
            numberOfEntries++;
            oldValue = null;
        } 
        else 
        {   // Key found; get old value for return and then replace it
            oldValue = hashTable[index].getValue();
            hashTable[index].setValue(value);
        } // end if

        // Ensure that hash table is large enough for another add
        if(isHashTableTooFull()) 
        {
            enlargeHashTable();
        }

        return oldValue;
    } // end if
} // end add
```

What changes should I make to the code to comply it with the current API and avoid getting these warnings? Please let me know any suggestions.

Comment: Why are you writing `(TableEntry<K,V>[]) new TableEntry[tableSize]` instead of `new TableEntry<K,V>[tableSize]`?

Comment: Also, your question would be clearer with the relevant source code.

Comment: I don't know how to post a 500 line source code. Please can someone help/explain me how to post it in code format.

Comment: Not the whole source code, just the areas where you're getting the warnings

Comment: @DonHosek code snippets are posted. Writing new TableEntry<K,V>[tableSize] is giving me an error "generic array creation"